# how to create each string into each list inside a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list :

```
list1 = ['move','study','go']
```

I expect the result to be like this :

```
list2 = [['move'],['study'],['go']]
```

anyone can explain the python code? thanks

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. We're a community that will give concrete answers to your concrete questions. What have you tried so far? What issues did you run into?

Comment: I do not understand how `list2` is expected without any code between. Can you show it?

Comment: @Alexander You mean....questions like....[this](http://www.specifyconcrete.org/specification-resources/concrete-faqs/#faq1)?

Comment: @ChristianDean Not quite :p

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "do my work" question.

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension:

```
list2 = [[str] for str in list1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think **list comprehension** is your best bet. There is a nice visually explained tutorial by **Trey Hunner**. Check it out. [Python List Comprehensions: Explained Visually](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

PS - We are not gonna write code for anyone. Just Q&A.